# Unable to load videos from AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have created a web-app to upload videos from rails application to AWS S3 bucket. I am able to successfully upload the videos on s3. For this I have been referring this [Link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) But I am facing issues while playing of the videos.

Following are my settings for AWS S3:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_region: ENV["AWS_REGION"],
    s3_host_name: 's3.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"],
      access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
      secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
    },
    s3_protocol: 'https'
  }
```

I am unable to play the videos after loading the page.

Comment: Can you download the video just by going to the S3 link in a browser? If not, is it a permissions error? Does your rails app log any errors when trying to load the video?

Comment: @Houseman Yes when I go to the S3 link in browser, file gets downloaded. And I am not getting any errors in rails logs and browser logs as well.

Comment: When your rails app supposedly makes the request for the video, do you see a network request to go out to your asset in your browser debugging tools? (i.e chrome developer console)